# Question asked 'according to the bible' was closed as duplicate but duplicate was 'Is there a Church Tradition'. Why?

Tags: bug, specific-question, closed-questions

[According to the Bible, which of Jesus' Apostles were baptised in water?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/99973/according-to-the-bible-which-of-jesus-apostles-were-baptised-in-water)

was closed as a 'duplicate'.

The 'dupliate' was stated as :

[Is there a Church Tradition that the original Apostles were ever baptized?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/95496/is-there-a-church-tradition-that-the-original-apostles-were-ever-baptized)

but this is asking about Church Tradition not about the content of the bible.

Why was the question closed, please ?

Andrew and John (the disciple whom Jesus loved) followed John the Baptist and all the followers of John were baptised. It is as certain as can be ascertained that these two were baptised, according to the biblical narrative.

It is particular traditions that exclude these two baptisms for purely denominational reasons.

Comment: The fault is mine.  My unedited question was not clear and even after editing it, I didn't think to include the 'biblical-basis' tag until I saw Ken Graham's response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question asked 'according to the bible' was closed as duplicate but duplicate was 'Is there a Church Tradition'. Why?**

My opening line to the second question goes on as such:

> Many churches hold that the Apostles were indeed baptized.
>
> The Scriptures in themselves do not reveal anything about this. But, it makes logical sense that they were in fact baptized.

The Scriptures are completely void of information on the subject according to the Bible. However, logic would seem to say that the Apostles did receive the baptism of Christ. They would have naturally fulfilled Christ's precepts about the necessity of the sacrament of baptism and would have been baptized either by Jesus himself or by one another. The Bible simply does not say they did, but it is obvious that they were all baptized.

Besides that I closed the post prior to its' editing and will let the community reopen it if they fell it should be opened again. The original edition was as such:

> **Which of Jesus' Apostles were baptised in water?**
>
> John the Baptist said to those who came to him to be baptised that he baptised with water for repentance: “But after me comes one who is more powerful than I. . . . He will baptise you with the Holy Spirit and fire” (Matthew 3:11). John the Baptist distinguished his baptism (with water) from the Lord’s baptism (with the Holy Spirit).
>
> John 1:35-40 mentions two of John the Baptist's disciples, Andrew (Simon Peter's brother) and the other, almost certainly the writer of the Gospel of John. They would have been baptised in water by John the Baptist (a baptism of repentance).
>
> Later, John 4:21 informs us that “Jesus learned that the Pharisees had heard that he was gaining and baptising more disciples than John [the Baptist], although in fact it was not Jesus who baptised, but his disciples.”
>
> Apart from knowing that Andrew and John were baptised by John the Baptist, does the New Testament say if any other of Jesus' apostles were ever baptised in water, and if any of the apostles were baptised by Jesus?

The original question was tagged only Baptism and Apostles which is still set as the only tags in the new edition. Although a minor issue, the tags bible and/or biblical-bases should be added. That would help in making new editing more clear in its intention

I meant no harm in closing the question, but it seems like a duplicate in the long run.

If the community desires to open the newly worded question, if am fine with that.

Comment: Thank you. Up-voted +1. Yes, I can see why it was closed but I still see it as a different focus. As you say, we shall see if the community wish to re-open.

Comment: My apologies for failing to make clear that I was looking for a biblical basis answer and did not add that tag till now. I've not been firing on all four cylinders for the past 24 hours.

Comment: @Lesley No worries. Looks like it will get reopened.

Comment: Many thanks, and for adding "Also what have biblical scholars said said about this?" as a concluding sentence to the question.